# Kali 801 not upgraded?

Tags: kali-linux, updates

I had kali 2019. I ran update then upgraded and then things are messed up.

How can I resolve this? I tried `apt dist-upgrade` with no luck.

What's wrong? 801 packages not upgraded

Comment: This isn't a question about Information Security, and therefore off-topic.

Comment: This could be problem with your source list.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking `apt dist-upgrate` with `apt-get dist-upgrade`. They're not identical, as counter intuitive as that may seem.

To upgrade everything, run `apt full-upgrade`. From the man page:

> ```
> full-upgrade (apt-get(8))
>       full-upgrade performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole.
> ```

Comment: I get this The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.3.0-6 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.